# In snowflake Is there a way to clone database, schema or table with out the data?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, cloning

We'd like to clone just the metadata. Currently, it seems snowflake just allows cloning with data. We'd like to clone just the objects with out data. is it possible ?

Answer (score 5):

There are a few solutions to this

Clone and Truncate

```
CREATE TABLE myNewTable CLONE myTable;
TRUNCATE TABLE myNewTable;
```

Create Table As Select with a filter

```
CREATE TABLE myNewTable AS
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE 1=0;
```

Generate the DDL for the table, and then run it

```
SELECT GET_DDL( 'table' , 'mytable' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Seems the simplest way is to get ddls using "SELECT GET_DDL( 'database' , 'mydatabase' );". This gives ddl for all objects + schema . Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For a single table,

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table COPY GRANTS;
```

This question has been asked and answered multiple times, like here:
[Clone Snowflake metadata only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59036431/clone-snowflake-metadata-only) by Mike Walton.

Suggested answer for `SCHEMA` and `DATABASE` in link:

1. `CREATE <object> new_obj CLONE old_obj`
2. For all tables in new_obj: `TRUNCATE TABLE obj_table`